# Laravel correct condition handling

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function on my site that creates a promo code for an affiliate automatically once every 24 hours. If 24 hours have passed since the creation of the promo code, it is deleted old promo from the database, and a new one is generated anew. But now there is a problem with this function, it generates a new promo code every time, regardless of whether 24 hours have passed or not.

My function:

```
    public function autoGroupPromos()
    {

        $userList = Promo::get();
        $userIds = $userList->pluck('user_id');


        foreach ($userIds as $id)  {
            $date = Carbon::now();
            $promoCodes = Promocode::query()->where('vk_user_id', '!=', null)->get();
            foreach ($promoCodes as $promos) {

                // If promo create 24 hours ago
                $hours = $promos->created_at->diffInHours($date);
                if ($hours >= 24) {
                    $promos->delete();
                }
            }

            $permitted_chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
            $code = substr(str_shuffle($permitted_chars), 0, 8);

                    Promocode::query()->create([
                        'name' => $code,
                        'sum' => '0.25',
                        'activates' => '100',
                        'vk_user_id' => $id
                    ]);


                    $promoText = Promocode::where('vk_user_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
                    $promoName = $promoText->name;


                    $message = 'Your new promo: ' . $promoName . ';

                    $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send';
                    $params = array(
                        'message' => $message,  
                        'access_token' => 'token',
                        'v' => '5.81',
                        'peer_ids' => $id
                    );

                    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
                        'http' => array(
                            'method' => 'POST',
                            'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                            'content' => http_build_query($params)
                        )
                    )));
        }
    }
```

That is, if less than 24 hours have passed since the promo was created - it should not be deleted and a new promo code should not be generated. But now unfortunately there is an error somewhere.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Put the creation under the `if ($hours >= 24) {` where you also delete the old one.

Comment: @apokryfos if i put under `if ($hours >= 24)`, nothing is created :(

Comment: Can you show us your error log?

Comment: @FelixMaxime laravel.log is empty... how i understand, the problem is that you need to compare with some value (for example, true or false), and then create a promo code. but I can not understand what to compare with :(

Comment: How is this function being run? In a schedule task? Every time you run this function, you will generate a new promocode and delete those over 24h old. So if you run this 100 times, you will get 100 new promocodes for the next 24h. Is this intentional?

Comment: @FelixMaxime a little different, the generation will take place on cron, every 15 minutes I'm going to run a task to check the old promo codes and issue new ones. if 24 hours have not passed since the creation of a promo code - nothing happens, if 24 hours have passed - the old are removed, new are added. and this task will not run for one person, but for all who are in the model Promo

Comment: So what is stopping this function from running if there exists promocodes under 24h?

Comment: @FelixMaxime Nothing prevents, but the problem is the code that now, even if it has not yet passed 24 hours, promo codes are still created, and the old are not removed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
function autoGroupPromos()
{
  // removed for loop to clean outdated promos in single request
  // note that this way of deleting rows won't fire model events (if any)
  Promocode::whereNotNull('vk_user_id')
    ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDay(1))
    ->delete();

  $permitted_chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

  $userIds = Promo::pluck('user_id');  
  
  foreach ($userIds as $id) {
    /* in the begining we cleaned all outdated codes, so if user still has 
     some - no need to create new */
    if (Promocode::where('vk_user_id', $id)->exists()){
      continue;
    }

    $code = substr(str_shuffle($permitted_chars), 0, 8);
    /* you can immidiately get create model like this - 
       no need to make another request
    $createdPromo = Promocode::create([*/
    Promocode::create([
      'name' => $code,
      'sum' => '0.25',
      'activates' => '100',
      'vk_user_id' => $id
    ]);

    /* didn't get why you were requesting newly created 
    promo to get name field if you put there $code value */
    $message = `Your new promo: $code`;

    $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send';
    $params = array(
      'message' => $message,
      'access_token' => 'token',
      'v' => '5.81',
      'peer_ids' => $id
    );

    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
      'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query($params)
      )
    )));
  }
}
```

upd: here can be a bit cleaner way with [hasOneOfMany](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many) and skipping each user request to check if promocode exists

```php
// User model
public function promocodes() {
  return $this->hasMany(Promocode::class);
}

public function promocode() {
  return $this->hasOne(Promocode::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

```php
function autoGroupPromos()
{
  // note that this way of deleting rows won't fire model events (if any)
  Promocode::whereNotNull('vk_user_id')
    ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDay(1))
    ->delete();

  $permitted_chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

  // taking users without promo after cleanup
  User::whereDoesntHave('promo')->get()
    ->each(function (User $user) use ($permitted_chars) {
      $code = substr(str_shuffle($permitted_chars), 0, 8);
      // pay attention on relation name - using hasMany
      $user->promocodes()->save(
        new Promocode([
          'name' => $code,
          'sum' => '0.25',
          'activates' => '100',
        ])
      );

      $message = `Your new promo: $code`;

      $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send';
      $params = array(
        'message' => $message,
        'access_token' => 'token',
        'v' => '5.81',
        'peer_ids' => $id
      );

      $result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
          'method' => 'POST',
          'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'content' => http_build_query($params)
        )
      )));
    });
}
```

link [Inserting & Updating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)